# agrandar o achicar texto dependiendo del tamaño del texto con pillow python

Tags: python

estoy tratando de agrandar o achicar el texto dependiendo de lo grande que sea el tamaño del texto pero no se como hacerlo... aquí dejo mi codigo:

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradeceria

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import json
import requests
  






  
img2 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 
img1 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 


draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
font = ImageFont.truetype("BurbankBigCondensed-Black.otf", 60)
draw.text((100, 400), f"hola", font=font, fill="white")  
img1.paste(img2,(0,0), mask = img2) 
img1.save("cosmetico.png")
```

Lo que queria hacer es que no se sobre salga el texto de la imagen

esto no deberia de ocurrir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deberia de ocurrir es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, no se pueden ver las imágenes

Comment: perdon, Ya estan añadidas

Comment: Hacer eso es dificil. Si hay una formula para lograr eso, no he logrado encontrarla ni deducirla. [Hay una pregunta parecida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902198/pil-how-to-scale-text-size-in-relation-to-the-size-of-the-image) en stackoverflow en ingles, pero de las pocas respuestas que hay, dos consisten en probar cada tamaño de la fuente hasta llegar al tamaño adecuado (algo en mi opinion poco eficiente). Yo diría que tu mejor opción es [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902198/pil-how-to-scale-text-size-in-relation-to-the-size-of-the-image/66091387#66091387).